# Why include (Eq t) in the signature for t -> [t] -> [t] when working with Haskell lists?

Tags: haskell, types, typeclass

I am working with functions that use lists of  type t elements. It means that the list can be a list of integers or a list of strings or characters. But i can't get why (Eq t) has to be in the type signature.

For example

```
belong :: (Eq t) => t -> [t] -> Bool    
belong e [] = False
belong e (x:xs) | e == x = True
                | otherwise = belong e xs
```

-- **WHY (Eq t) is in the signature?**

Comment: Because you use `e == x`.

Comment: There are two very different answers, depending on whether you believe something like `(+) == (+)` should work or not.

Answer (score 5):

You make a comparison of the list element `x` with an item `e`, `e == x`. It is an operation which tests these two items of type `t` for equality. To do it the items themselves must be comparable, because you cannot just compare two arbitrary things with each other. You function is *parametrically polimorphic* in type `t` which is an unconstrained type variable, so the type can be anything and it is not possible to reason in general about possible morphisms on that type.

Class constraint `(Eq t) =>` in function signature tells that the type `t` should belong to the typeclass `Eq`. It *expresses the requirement* that the items of the list and the item you are comparing them to must be comparable.

```
class Eq a where
  (==) :: a -> a -> Bool
   ...
```

Typeclass `Eq` defines the function `==` having the type `a -> a -> Bool`, it is like an 'interface', which all types implementing this typeclass would have.

The exact implementation of the `==` function would be deretmined based on the *instance* of the `Eq` typeclass for the concrete type used for `t`; it is an example of the *ad-hoc polymorphism*, where each concrete value adopts a typeclass because it has been given a separate definition for this typeclass.

Answer (score 2):

In the "*guard*", you write `e == x`. Now in order to check if two items are equal, we thus use `(==) :: Eq a => a -> a -> Bool`. Not for every type this function is available, as the type signature already says, one needs to make that type an instance of the `Eq` typeclass to define when two items are equivalent.

The function can however be simplified to:

```
belong :: Eq t => t -> [t] -> Bool
belong e [] = False
belong e (x:xs) = e == x || belong e xs
```

or with a `any` to work on any `Foldable`:

```
belong :: (Eq t, Foldable f) => t -> f t -> Bool    
belong = any . (==)
```

Since `base-4.8` your function already exists with this generic signature in the `Prelude`: [**`elem :: (Eq a, Foldable f) => a -> f a -> Bool`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:elem).